# How to properly instantiate HttpContext object?

Tags: c#, asp.net, nullreferenceexception

I am trying to create a simple code to retrieve a string for the current url as follows:

```
string currentURL = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString();
```

However, I get the error upon running the code: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

I assume I have to create an instance of HttpContext. The arguments for HttpContext are either `HttpContext(HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response)` or `HttpContext(HttpWorkerRequest wr)`.

Is there documentation that details how to work with these arguments? I'm fairly new to C#, so I'm not entirely sure how to instantiate this object properly, and have not found any resources that have been helpful (including MS library).

Comment: Why do you have to *create an instance* of `HttpContext`? **Where is this code located?** You don't want to create it on your own, it's created when routing occurs.

Comment: Sounds like you are making a utility class. In that case work with HttpContext within your codebehind and do anything utility-like in the utility class. I've had this issue before.

Comment: The fact that you're getting an `ObjectReference` exception doesn't mean that the `Current` context is `null`. You have two other chained properties that could throw that error. Are you certain it's the `Current` context property?

Comment: Hi @neoistheone, to be honest I am not sure that it's the `Current` context property, I was assuming that was where the exception was occurring. After inputting Mark's solution, I continue to get the `ObjectReference` exception, so I am not sure where the issue lies within the `HttpContext` line.

Comment: @TestK, well I would say throw a breakpoint on that line and figure out **which property** is `null`. That will be step 1.

Comment: Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `HttpContext` object is instantiated, once per request thread, by the ASP.NET infrastructure. **You have to be running ASP.NET on a web server** (e.g., IIS) for it to be available. It is not meant to be initialized in user code. You are already accessing that instance through the `HttpContext.Current`  static property. **It will be null** if you are *not* running ASP.NET.

If you really wanted to, though, you could instantiate one based on the request and response of an existing `HttpContext`:

```
var request    = HttpContext.Current.Request;
var response   = HttpContext.Current.Response;
var newContext = new HttpContext(request, response);
```